# Удаление нужных элементов из списка

Tags: python

Имеется список list_of_elements, а также список булевых значений del_mapper. Требуется из списка list_of_elements удалить те значения, по индексам которых в списке del_mapper стоит True. То есть нужно удалить из списка list_of_elements первый и третий элементы.

```
list_of_elements = [1, 2, 4, 2, 12, 83]
del_mapper = [True, False, True]
result = [2, 2, 12, 83]
```

Как этого добиться, не создавая промежуточных списков и просто из списка list_of_elements получить нужный результат видоизменив его содержимое?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> не создавая промежуточных списков и просто из списка list_of_elements
>   получить нужный результат видоизменив его содержимое

Шаги:

- Перебор индексов `del_mapper` в обратном порядке, чтобы при удалении элементов `list_of_elements` порядок индексов оставался актуальным
- Проверка значения флага `del_mapper[i]`
- Возможно, понадобится добавить проверку `i` -- чтобы не было выхода за пределы `list_of_elements`

Попробуйте:

```
list_of_elements = [1, 2, 4, 2, 12, 83]
del_mapper = [True, False, True]

for i in reversed(range(len(del_mapper))):
    if del_mapper[i]:
        list_of_elements.pop(i)

print(list_of_elements)
# [2, 2, 12, 83]
```

Comment: Спасибо, я последовал вашему совет, только написал код иначе. Код ниже в комментарии.

Comment: ```for idx, skip in list(enumerate(del_mapper))[::-1]:
        if skip:
            del list_of_elements[idx]```
```list(enumerate(del_mapper))[::-1]``` - как-то уродливо получилось.

Comment: Не знаю как оставить код в комментариях. Получается сплошным текстом в одной строке.

Comment: @ХачатурСаркисян, я тоже хотел что-то подобное сделать `list(enumerate(del_mapper))[::-1]`, но это два раза создает списки: первый раз в `list(...)` второй раз `[::-1]` :)